# Update a field value to random number

Tags: apex

I want to do a bulk update on any  when the filed  have a null value. Update the field to have random number. Kindly help me with code.

Comment: Have you looked at Math.random() function? Or maybe just Datetime in epoch format? What is the use case for updating a random number?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? SFSE is happy to help with specific technical problems, but strongly discourages requests for others to write code for you. See [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you use the Math.random() function to get random numbers.

Math.random() function returns a value :- A floating-point, pseudo-random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

Here in this example given below, I have used 100. This 100 is a limit of the range of random number like it will generate random values from 0 to 100(exclusive) because if I don't use any value as a limit like this

```
Integer randomNumber = Integer.valueOf(Math.random());
```

then it will generate a value between 0(inclusive) and 1(exclusive) and as I am getting values in Integer data-type, I will only get 0 as output(in the case when don't give any limit).

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, NumberOfEmployees FROM Account WHERE NumberOfEmployees = null LIMIT 1000];
for(Account acc: accList){
    Integer randomNumber = Integer.valueOf((Math.random()*100));
    acc.NumberOfEmployees = randomNumber;
}
update accList;
System.debug(accList);
```

Hope this explanation will resolve your query.

Thanks

Akshay